# Python 'list out of index error'

Tags: python-3.x

I had written a code to read data from file for interpolation but when i run the program is saying list out of index error at "pointsx.append(float(words[0])):

```
with open("points.dat","r") as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     pointsx = []
     pointsy = []
     for line in data:
            words=(line.split())
            pointsx.append(float(words[0]))
            pointsy.append(float(words[1]))

x = float(input('Enter the  value of X:\n'))

i=0
lenx=len(pointsx)

if x<pointsx[0]:\n
        print("this Particular value of X is lower than the range of interpolation \n")
elif x>pointsx[lenx-1]:
        print("This particular value of x is higher than the range of interpolation\n")
else:
        for i in range(lenx-1):
                if(x<=pointsx[i]):
                         break;


                y=pointsy[i-1]+((pointsy[i]-pointsy[i-1])/(pointsx[i]-pointsx[i-1]))*(x-pointsx[i-1])
                print("The required value of y is ",y,"\n")


f.close()
```

Comment: is there any chance that your file contains empty lines? (even at its end)

Comment: ohh thank you a lot. There was a empty lines at the end. It is resolved now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluding from your comment, `words=(line.split())` fills `words` with `[]`. Therefore, `pointsx.append(float(words[0]))` tries to reach the first element of `words` which throws the exception.
Check the size of `words` before that line.